# namespace XML JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, schema

I would like to get out put xml like it:

```
    <pracownicy_kadry xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/kadra1 kadra1.xsd"  
xmlns="http://www.example.org/kadra1"
xmlns:kadra="http://www.example.org/kadra1">
    <opis_dokumentu>
        <tytuł>Skoczkowie i trenerzy</tytuł>
        <autor xmlns="http://osoba.example.com"  >
            <imię>FirstName</imię>
            <nazwisko>LastName</nazwisko>
            <nr_indeksu>165415</nr_indeksu>
        </autor>
        <last_mod>2012-11-04</last_mod>
    </opis_dokumentu>
    <zawodnicy>
        <zawodnik kadra:id_kad="A1" kadra:id_trenera="T2">
        <imię>Adam</imię>
        <nazwisko>Małysz</nazwisko>
         <Kadra>seniorzy</Kadra>
        <data_ur>1980-03-03</data_ur>
        <adres>
            <miejscowość>Wisła</miejscowość>
            <ulica>Żeromskiego</ulica>
            <nr_domu>23</nr_domu>
            <nr_mieszkania>1</nr_mieszkania>
            <kod>26-600</kod>           
        </adres>    
        <bmi>1.0</bmi>
        <kontakt>
            <email>123@gmail.com</email>
            <telefon_komórkowy>123456789</telefon_komórkowy>
        </kontakt>
    </zawodnik>

    <zawodnik kadra:id_kad="A2" kadra:id_trenera="T3">
        <imię>Stefan</imię>
        <nazwisko>Bachleda</nazwisko>
         <Kadra>seniorzy</Kadra>
         <data_ur>1980-03-03</data_ur>
        <adres>
            <miejscowość>Wisła</miejscowość>
            <ulica>Żeromskiego</ulica>
            <nr_domu>23</nr_domu>
            <nr_mieszkania>1</nr_mieszkania>
            <kod>26-600</kod>

        </adres>    
        <bmi>1.0</bmi>
        <kontakt>
            <email>123@gmail.com</email>
            <telefon_komórkowy>123456789</telefon_komórkowy>
        </kontakt>
    </zawodnik>
     <zawodnik kadra:id_kad="A3" kadra:id_trenera="T2">
        <imię>Kamil</imię>
        <nazwisko>Stoch</nazwisko>
         <Kadra>seniorzy</Kadra>
        <data_ur>1980-03-03</data_ur>
        <adres>
            <miejscowość>Płock</miejscowość>
            <ulica>Żółta</ulica>
            <nr_domu>823</nr_domu>
            <nr_mieszkania>1</nr_mieszkania>
            <kod>26-600</kod>           
        </adres>    
        <bmi>1.0</bmi>
        <kontakt>
            <email>kstoch@gmail.com</email>
            <telefon_komórkowy>123456789</telefon_komórkowy>
        </kontakt>
    </zawodnik>
    <zawodnik kadra:id_kad="A5" kadra:id_trenera="T2">
        <imię>Robert</imię>
...
```

I use a JAXB and a get all class from my xsd file. I used xjc. I don't know how can I get the xml with namespace I get something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pracownicy_kadry xmlns="http://osoba.example.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/kadra1">
    <opisDokumentu>
        <tytul>Skoczkowie</tytul>
        <autor>
            <imie>Sebastian</imie>
            <nazwisko>Jakowski</nazwisko>
            <nr_indeksu>165415</nr_indeksu>
        </autor>
        <lastMod>0001-03-05T09:45:46.618+01:00</lastMod>
    </opisDokumentu>
    <zawodnicy/>
    <trenerzy>
        <ns2:trener ns2:id_tren="T12">
            <ns2:imie>Roman</ns2:imie>
            <ns2:nazwisko>romanski</ns2:nazwisko>
            <ns2:data_ur>0001-03-05T00:00:00+01:00</ns2:data_ur>
            <ns2:adres>
```

When I get good xml I have to check validation with my xsd file.
Thanks for your replay and Happy New Year :)

Comment: Is there a namespace qualification that is wrong in your XML document or are you trying to get a particular prefix used?